# tunnel ssh from another pc to docker

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, openssh

i am trying to create a ssh tunnel for executing conky in my contenair.
 pc --> server --> contenair(docker) 
i can create a tunnel from my pc to the server and from the server to contenair 
but i don't know why i can't execute this command from my pc to create a tunnel all the way:

```
ssh -L 8888:localhost:22 user@62.210.227.219 ssh -t -t -L 8887:localhost:8888 -p 8888 admin@localhost
```

i get a terminal with nothing.   :(

the ssh log from my server

```
Aug  9 14:57:14 sd-46208 sshd[5867]: Accepted publickey for USER from 82.64.127.210 port 54369 ssh2: RSA 39:50:42:5p:05:0a:7a:f4:66:fb:5d:24:1f:96:09:5f
Aug  9 14:57:14 sd-46208 systemd: Starting Session 1810 of user USER.
Aug  9 14:57:14 sd-46208 systemd: Started Session 1810 of user USER.
Aug  9 14:57:14 sd-46208 systemd: Failed to reset devices.list on /system.slice: Invalid argument
Aug  9 14:57:14 sd-46208 systemd-logind: New session 1810 of user USER.
Aug  9 14:57:14 sd-46208 sshd[5870]: error: Failed to disconnect from controlling tty.
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you add more details of ports and services you need access to ?

Comment: what i try is to create ssh tunnel  from pc to docker  so  i try that ssh -X  -L 8888:localhost:8890 USER@62.210.227.219 ssh -X -L  8890:localhost:8888  admin@localhost -p 8888 .

Comment: 8888 is a port of my ssh on docker

Comment: what i try exactly is to execute a programme on my contenair and get the interface on my pc, same as execute gedit on your pc but it's not it's on your contenair

Comment: Is SSH server a running process on the Docker instance? I presume so if you were able to connect from the server. Only checking as Docker often only allow one running process, not always but often.

Answer (score 0):

i almost solved my problem 
i added in ssh/sshd_config

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
AddressFamily inet
```

and i run

ssh User@60.220.207.219 ssh User@127.0.0.1 -p 9999  i can connect to contenair but i cant execute an application for the moment